# How to use incremental refresh against Log Analytics in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-log-analytics

I am working on a case implementing incremental refresh in Power BI against Log Analytics in my Power BI Premium dataset. Log Analytics is set up to log Synapse pipelines and we will perhaps extend the use. Right now I have set up Log Analytics, created a Synapse pipeline that fails, and I am able to get that log data out of Log analytics. Then I have created a Power query that reads the data. It is set up with RangeStart and RangeEnd inside the kusto query, and it works (below you see my power query code). I publish the report to power bi service, set the credential and everything works. I even check the partition in Tabular Editor to validate this. But the problem is that my credential is limited through the PIM settings on the azure subscription. Right now my connection dies after 2 hours. Therefore I think that to make use of a service principal with clientid and secret. I can get this through key vault settings.

How do I do that in Power BI? I need to run my power bi report without my user account restriction regarding PIM.

[image]

When the PIM is not active
[image]

The picture above is ok after activating PIM.

In Tabular editor showing incremental refresh partitions
[image]

```
`let 
 strRangeStart = DateTime.ToText(RangeStart,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"]),
 strRangeEnd = DateTime.ToText(RangeEnd,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"]),


 Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/xxxxxxxx-1554-499b-a4ca-dcde7f3a4a90/query", 
[Query=[#"query"="
SynapseIntegrationPipelineRuns 
| where Level == '''Error'''

| where TimeGenerated >= datetime(" & strRangeStart &") 
| where TimeGenerated < datetime("& strRangeEnd &") 
| project PipelineName, RunId, Start, End, OperationName, Status

",#"x-ms-app"="OmsAnalyticsPBI",#"prefer"="ai.response-thinning=true"],Timeout=#duration(0,0,4,0)])),
TypeMap = #table(
{ "AnalyticsTypes", "Type" }, 
{ 
{ "string",   Text.Type },
{ "int",      Int32.Type },
{ "long",     Int64.Type },
{ "real",     Double.Type },
{ "timespan", Duration.Type },
{ "datetime", DateTimeZone.Type },
{ "bool",     Logical.Type },
{ "guid",     Text.Type },
{ "dynamic",  Text.Type }
}),
DataTable = Source[tables]{0},
Columns = Table.FromRecords(DataTable[columns]),
ColumnsWithType = Table.Join(Columns, {"type"}, TypeMap , {"AnalyticsTypes"}),
Rows = Table.FromRows(DataTable[rows], Columns[name]), 
Table = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows, Table.ToList(ColumnsWithType, (c) => { c{0}, c{3}}))
in
    Table`
```

===================================

Comment: I forgot to add the power query code

Comment: Found a solution yet? I have the same problem.